# Why was Mr. Smithers black and then white?

Tags: character, production, the-simpsons

In season 1, episode 2 of the Simpsons, Mr. Smithers has black skin. In later episodes, he has white skin. Does anyone know the reason for this change?

Comment: [Relevant google image search results.](https://www.google.com/search?q=black+smithers&tbm=isch)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Talking to TMZ, Matt Groening  said:

> He was always yellow, and they painted him wrong once. 'At the time
>   we didn't have enough to do retakes, so when there were glitches and
>   mistakes it stayed that way. 'He was never 'black', it was an
>   accident. (Source:[dailymail.co.uk](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2838753/Smithers-black-mistake-Simpsons-creator-Matt-Groening-reveals-Burns-assistant-started-different-color-reason-making-characters-yellow.html))

So he was always supposed to be yellow <strike>white</strike> like rest of the characters, not black. Now if you want to know why he is yellow; refer below mentioned question:-

[Why are the Simpsons yellow?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/why-are-the-simpsons-yellow)

Comment: Oddly enough, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waylon_Smithers) he was *supposed* to be black but this idea was scrapped.

Comment: @Walt source for that lines is [reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1012l4/jay_kogen_here_long_past_simpsons_writer_i/). I am not sure how much we can trust that.

Comment: 1. This is not from some informal reddit thread but rather from [an official online q&a session with Simpsons writer Jay Kogen](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1012l4/jay_kogen_here_long_past_simpsons_writer_i/) held in 2012. (You can read its highlights [here](http://splitsider.com/2012/09/buying-michael-jackson-20-cases-of-water-and-all-the-best-parts-from-former-simpsons-writer-jay-kogens-ama/)). Reddit has those from time to time. 2. Another quote on that Wikipedia page (from David Silverman) supports the claim, and it's from TV Guide.

Comment: @Walt i am quite unaware with how reddit work, so maybe both statement are right on their own way as you said in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24443032#24443032)